# python append 2d list not work as expect is it a bug?

Tags: python, python-3.x, append

I encountered an issue with appending a list to a 2D list. In the code below, if I change `b.append(a)` to `b.append([*a])` everything works! But aren't `a` and `[*a]` the same?

```
a = ['1', '1', '1']
b = []

def call_other(ar):
    a[0], a[1], a[2] = ar[0], ar[1], ar[2]
    print('a is', a)
    b.append(a)
    print('b is', b)
    print()

def lop():
    for i in range(5):
        c = ['0', '1', '1']
        if i >  1:
            c = ['1', '0', '1']
        call_other(c)

lop()           
print('final b:', b)
```

The output is:

```
a is ['0', '1', '1']
b is [['0', '1', '1']]

a is ['0', '1', '1']
b is [['0', '1', '1'], ['0', '1', '1']]

a is ['1', '0', '1']
b is [['1', '0', '1'], ['1', '0', '1'], ['1', '0', '1']]

a is ['1', '0', '1']
b is [['1', '0', '1'], ['1', '0', '1'], ['1', '0', '1'], ['1', '0', '1']]

a is ['1', '0', '1']
b is [['1', '0', '1'], ['1', '0', '1'], ['1', '0', '1'], ['1', '0', '1'], ['1', '0', '1']]

final b: [['1', '0', '1'], ['1', '0', '1'], ['1', '0', '1'], ['1', '0', '1'], ['1', '0', '1']]
```

Comment: What does _everything works_ look like?

Comment: `a` and `[*a]` can differ, depending on the type of `a`.

Comment: `a[0], a[1], a[2] = ar[0], ar[1], ar[2]` -> `a = ar[:]` or `a = ar[:3]`. Both are copies.

Comment: Look at print out final b should start with[ 0 1 1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a fundamental difference between the following two pieces of code:

```
a = [1, 1, 1]
b.append(a)
a[0] = 0
b.append(a)
```

and

```
a = [1, 1, 1]
b.append([*a])
a[0] = 0
b.append([*a])
```

In the first case, you are appending the same reference to `b` every time. When you modify an element of the original list `a` with `a[0] = 0`, the change will be visible to all references to that list. `b` will therefore be `[[0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1]]`, not `[[1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1]]`.

In the second case, `[*a]` makes a new list containing a copy of all the elements of `a`. When you update the original list, the reference that is already in `b` does not point to the same list, and so remains unchanged. That is why `b` will be `[[1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1]]`.

Comment: got it! when b.append(a) pass pointer of a to b instead of copy value. Thank you!